# Return dictionary insted of string in Graphql using graphene

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I want my graphql query to return multiple values in form of dictionary but i am only able to return the dictionary inside the string.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3LwE.png)

```
class Query(ObjectType):

get_reply = String(
    question=String(),
    sender=String(),
    timestamp=String()
)

def resolve_get_reply(root, info, question, sender, timestamp):
    written_to_database = False
    reply = 'hello'
    d = {"reply": reply, "wtd": written_to_database}
    return d
```

The existing guides have just confused me even more.
How do i define the schema for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set your get_reply variable as a String. You are therefore receiving a String as a response.

You can create a custom Reply class and set the get_reply as follows:

```
get_reply = graphene.Field(Reply, 
    question=String()
)
```

Comment: thank you 

i did as you said by adding a schema for Reply and everything worked smoothly